# Django Model Form Set POSTs But Does Not Save

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django site built on a model formset (`forms.py`). The model formset is picked up by my view (`views.py`). The view is rendered in my template (`alerts.html`). The user sees a list of alerts with entity and logic populated. They must enter a comment on one or more forms in the formset and then click the submit button to post the one or more forms to the DB. When the submit button is clicked currently, the page refreshes and a successful POST (200) displays in `runserver`, but the data is not saved to the DB. `formset.errors` shows that `comment` is required for each field, not just the form that was changed.

I tried adding `if formset.has_changed():` prior to calling `formset.save()`, but the problem persisted.

How should I alter my project to allow the model formset to be saved appropriately?

**EDIT:** I migrated `blank=True` for comment. Now when the submit button is clicked, the data is saved. However, the comment text (and the rest of the form) remains in the table in the template. When submit is clicked again, the comment text remains and `entity` and `logic` are replaced by blanks.

forms.py

```
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = [
            'comment'
        ]

AlertFormSet = modelformset_factory(Alert, extra=0, form=AlertForm)
```

views.py

```
def alerts(request):
    newAlerts = Alert.objects.filter(comment='')
    formset = AlertFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=newAlerts)
    context = {'formset':formset}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = formset
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = formset
    print(formset.errors)
    return render(request, 'alerts/alerts.html', context)
```

alerts.html

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-id-submit" type="submit">
  {% for form in formset %}
     {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
       {{ hidden_field }}
     {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Entity</th>
        <th>Logic</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     {% for form in formset %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ form.instance.entity }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.instance.logic }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.comment }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
    </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: I edited my answer hope it could help you solve the problem

Comment: @ZachB. thanks for the help! however, i've gone down the road of looping forms before, and i would really like to stick to submitting the whole formset. i know it's possible because of this (where I got the view code from): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-model-formset-in-a-view

Comment: Do you want `entity` and `logic` to be editable? You don't appear to be including those fields in the template. You haven't included any errors in the template -- they would give a hint what the problem is. It would be less confusing if you looped through `{% for form in formset %}` instead of `{% for field in formset %}`.

Comment: No, only comment needs to be editable. I will change `field` to `form` to make it less confusing - thanks! I am using `field.instance.entity` and `field.instance.logic` because they are foreign key fields, and I would like to see the related text rather than random id numbers

Comment: You have changed the loop to `{% for form in formset %}` but you still use `field` inside the loop, e.g. `{{ field.instance.entity }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formset is invalid because you are not submitting the values for the `entity` or `logic` fields. You would see this if you printed `formset.errors` in your view or [included the form errors in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

Since you don't want `entity` or `logic` to be editable, you should not include these in the formset's fields:

```
class AlertForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Alert
        fields = [
            'comment',
        ]
```

Since you are defining `fields` in the form, you shouldn't need to include `exclude` when you call `modelformset_factory`.

```
AlertFormSet = modelformset_factory(Alert, extra=0, form=AlertForm)
```

Comment: thank you - this would definitely work if there was only one form in the formset, but there are multiple. I think the key point is that the user can enter a comment for one or more forms, and they should be able to submit at any time. so right now there are 10 forms in the formset, rendered as an inline table. if the user enters a comment for one form and hits submit, `formset.errors` is showing that `comment` is required for the other nine forms

Comment: Then make comment an optional field (e.g. set blank=True on the model field).

Comment: I made those migrations, and now the data is being saved...however, the comment text and the form remains in the table after the redirect. when the submit button is clicked a second time (after the initial save), comment text remains and entity and logic become blank. `formset.errors` shows `[{}, {}, {} ..... {}]`

Comment: I can't explain that behaviour. The recommended approach is to redirect after a successful post request.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping over the data in the formset like this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = formset
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            entity = cleaned_data.get('entity')
            logic = cleaned_data.get('logic')
            comment = cleaned_data.get('comment')
            # create a new Alert object here
            alert = Alert(entity=entity, logic=logic, comment=comment)
            alert.save()
```

Comment: that didn't work - added `method="post"` to my button, and the same challenge exists

Comment: Whoops yeah I'm wrong that's supposed to be in the <form> tag which it already is, sorry :P

Comment: Is your console log showing a POST request to the server? Just not saving it?

Comment: yes, the dev server is showing a successful POST request (200), but the form (or forms if multiple are filled out) are not saving to the DB